# How can I specify maxConcurrency in flatMapSingle?

Tags: rx-java

I've found an overload of `flatMap` which takes a maxConcurrency parameter

> To limit the concurrency in flatMap, the idea is to request a maxConcurrency amount upfront via request(), and then whenever a source completes, request(1) extra.

Is there any way I can use it in flatMapSingle?

```
playersIdsObservable
    .distinct()
    .flatMapSingle(playerId -> dao.players().loadPlayerSRx(playerId))
```

I've found a buffer() operator which is kinda similar to what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no overload of `Observable.flatMapSingle` that allows you to specify the max concurrency. However, the plain `Observable.flatMap` does have such an overload and `Flowable.flatMapSingle` also supports limiting the concurrency. This gives two options:

1) convert the `Single` into an `Observable`:

```
playersIdsObservable
.distinct()
.flatMap(playerId -> 
    dao.players().loadPlayerSRx(playerId).toObservable(), maxConcurrency)
```

2) convert to `Flowable` with buffering backpressure strategy:

```
playersIdsObservable
.distinct()
.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
.flatMapSingle(playerId -> 
    dao.players().loadPlayerSRx(playerId), false, maxConcurrency)
```